# Page counter script. what is wrong?

Tags: php, counter

i made this script that add in a mysql database information about who have visited my website.

```
session_start()

if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])) { 
   $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   $browser=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   $browser=mysql_real_escape_string($browser);
   if(isset($_SESSION['nickname'])) {
       $user=$_SESSION['nickname'];
   } else {
       $user="unknownABCD1234";
   }
   $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO views (ip, user, date, browser) VALUES ('$ip', '$user', '$date', '$browser')", $mydb);  
   $_SESSION['log']='logged';
   $_SESSION['iplog']=$ip;
   $_SESSION['datelog']=$date;
}
```

the problem is that it adds the referencee for each user many times (but not ever, just sometimes). example, i find on my db infos like these :

```
ID: 1
IP : 95.108.244.252
USER : unknownABCD1234 
DATE : 2010-08-07 01:16:00
BROWSER : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)

ID : 2 
IP : 95.108.244.252 
USER : unknownABCD1234 
DATE : 2010-08-07 01:16:04
BROWSER : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
```

that's impossible no? i sure that the session during more than 4 seconds :) what happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bot is discarding session info and ignoring your cookies.

This means that it shows up multiple times in your log. Yes, it does hit your site quickly and without session info, so you don't filter it out.

Your best option is to have some kind of duplicate filter for bots or IPs that hit quickly and repeatedly this way. You might also try adding explicit ignores to the few bot user agents that cause this problem with your script. By the time you have 10 or 15, you'll have dealt with the majority of the problem UAs.

Comment: Bot? What bot? Dunno what you are saying :) these example is when i try to add on my website (me, not a bot). It ignore the $_SESSION['log'] variable o_O

Comment: No, they aren't you. YandexBot is a Russian search engine spider.

Comment: damn!!!! So these are bots who discard sessions! Sorry now i understand ehhehe :) but why these kind of bots open my website only 1/2 time for example?

Comment: That's a hard question. Better ask their makers... But they may only be interested in some of your content.

Comment: @markzzz not only bots. Many people do not like then someone is tracking their movements. In my browser cookie support is turned off by default. In your place I would not mess with cookies but counted just IPs - it's much easier and reliable enough.

Comment: okok ;) tnx for the answer. i need to find out a solution... where can i find the list of these bot? i think if i ignore 10-15 it's ok :) (if some bot add some lines...it doesnt make the real difference ehhe)

Comment: @markzzz actually you will be spammed with bot's requests. I wouldn't call it "not a real difference". Your optimism is much higher than your knowledge. I'd suggest to equalize it a bit.

Comment: uhm yeah...but in fact i can't think to a real solution. I can add a list of knowed bots, but after it? any suggestion would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Write `session_start()` at the start of code. (For more clarity in the question)

Although default session timeout is 1440 sec in PHP. By default, session closes after browser shutdown. Knowing that the application log contains a bot, most likely it is doing the same thing. (opening and closing the connections)

Comment: hehe yeah of course that only a part of my page, just the part where i put info about user.